# Linq to XML - parse a node into dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I can't figure this one out myself. My XML file looks like this:

```
<section name="blah">
   <setting1 name="blah">blah</setting1>
   <setting1 name="blah1">blah1</setting1>
</section>

<section name="foo">
   <setting2 name="sth">sth</setting2>
   <setting2 name="sth1">lala</setting2>
</section>
```

And so on.

What I would like to do is parse each section into it's own individual Dictionary, like this:

```
Dictionary <string, string> foo;
Dictionary <string, string> blah;

XElement xelement = XElement.Load("test.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> sections = xelement.Elements();
foreach (var section in sections)
{
    switch (section.Attribute("name").Value)
    {
        case "foo":
            foo = ... Something
            break;

        case "blah":
            blah = ... Something
            break;
    }
}
```

And so on.

After parsing:

```
foo["sth1"] <---- contains lala
blah["blah1"] <---- contains blah1
```

How can I achieve this in Linq?

Comment: So do you *only* want the `foo` element? What about `blah`?

Comment: I want all the elements. I've edited the code to make it clear.

Comment: It seems that a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` would be a better bet then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you *could* hard-code the names as variables, I suspect you'd be better off with a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`:

```
var settings = element.Elements("section")
     .ToDictionary(section => section.Attribute("name").Value,
                   section => section.Elements()
                       .ToDictionary(setting => setting.Attribute("name)".Value,
                                     setting => setting.Value));

Console.WriteLine(settings["foo"]["sth1"]); // lala
```

This uses a nested call to [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), where you specify the key and the value given any particular item. The value of each element of the outer dictionary is itself a dictionary, created from the elements within the section.

Comment: That makes sense. I wanted to hardcode it because I hadn't realized the actual tag names (as in <setting1>) do not matter (don't ask me why). Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary <string, string> foo=new Dictionary<string,string>();
Dictionary <string, string> blah;

XElement xelement = XElement.Load("D:\\x.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> sections = xelement.Elements();
     foreach (var section in sections)
     {
          switch (section.Attribute("name").Value)
          {
              case "foo":
                    foreach (XElement element in section.Descendants().Where(p => p.HasElements == false))
        {
            int keyInt = 0;
            string keyName = element.Attribute("name").Value;

            while (foo.ContainsKey(keyName))
                keyName = element.Attribute("name") + "_" + keyInt++;

            foo.Add(keyName, element.Value);
        }
        foo.Dump();

                   break;

              case "blah":

                   break;
          }
     }
```